# How can we reduce the apk size in flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, apk

I'm building my apk with flutter build apk --split-per-abi but it still generate 60mb apk. [1# Here is the result of size analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HROgt.png) [2#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Keqd.png)[pubspec.yaml  all the packages that is used in this project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRmzk.png)

I tried removing all the unused package but it didn't work after that I created new project same result .It should not be that large for ios it goes to 900+mbs

Comment: run `flutter clean` then build your app

Comment: @eamirho3ein Thanks But I already did that many time but it result same.

Answer (score 0):

if your plan is publish to google play you can export appbundle for android devices

```
flutter build appbundle
```